# How to convert Month in character to number, for example, September to 9

Tags: r

I am working with a df, one column is factor, value from January to December, I want to convert them into numbers, such as January ——> 1

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: see `month.name`, i.e. `match('January', month.name)`

Comment: `df$month.num <- which(month.name == df["name_of_month_column"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- c("September", "December", "January")
match(x, month.name)

[1]  9 12  1
```

Comment: Good option with `match`